# Image from database not appearing in same dimension as without database

Tags: php, html, css, database, frontend

I am making an e-commerce website in php with mysql database, I am using a web template for front-end, the issue is when I try to upload the image from database, it is not showing in proper **dimension**, however when i upload the same image **without database** it works and shows in proper size as defined in template. I don't know why is this happening because there are same css and same image class define for both.

Here is the screenshot of image in without database:

[image]

And below with fetching from database:

[image]

I am stuck how to make image display same as without database.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add width and height to the image at front end  and only retrieve image in src tag
This can fix your problem

& if it didn't fix please provide your code snap